# Why can I see the information on the website but cannot see it on the website's source code page?

Tags: web, web-crawler

I want to curl data from [this website](http://www.shtdsc.com/2016/tdjy/dkxx/crdk/?id=201800101), and I found the information I need in the element section of the google dev tool, showed in this picture.
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RZj9.png) However, when I click the document where the information lies in, the page is empty, showed in this picture.[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8F9a.png)
So what's the problem here? I have never encountered this situation before, hope you can help me!

Comment: Usually the content is loaded by Ajax. Your crawler would then need to be able to execute script, or alternatively, just use Selenium (way more CPU & RAM usage though)

Comment: Thank you! I used selenium but it can only visit the front page(http://www.shtdsc.com/). I tried downloading the website to local and magically found  the information I need. Now I'm trying to read the local html file to R and I'll post my solution here if I succeed.